# Weird-shaped jelly doughnuts

Tags: baking, doughnuts

I tried making [Sufganiot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufganiyah) (a kind of jelly doughnut) this Hanukkah, and ran into a problem. I've let the dough rise, made balls, then let them rise again. However, all balls split along the seam lines (where I've rolled a piece of dough that wasn't originally ball-shaped into a ball), resulting in doughnuts that were very far from round.

What did I do wrong, and how can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you roll balls out of dough you want to roll/knead them until the seam lines vanish. Otherwise, as you noticed, they will split along the lines.